# What is my Client ID in GoInstant?

Tags: rest, curl, goinstant

GoInstant has recently uncovered their [REST API](https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/rest-api/getting_started.html), as you may know.

I was looking at the documentation (link above), and I saw that you needed a client ID.

What is that? I couldn't find it on their website, and contacting them usually takes around at least 2 hours to respond (which is perfectly normal, as it is an email conversation).

There is also a client secret, which (please correct me if I'm wrong) I think is the application secret key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a `client_id` by going to the [credentials page](https://goinstant.com/dashboard/credentials) on the dashboard.  Just give it a description and it'll generate both `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Comment: Also, it's [documented here](https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/rest-api/authentication.html)